# How do I use Factory girl to create a company?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have this factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email               { Faker::Internet.email }
    first_name          { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name           { Faker::Name.last_name }
    password            { 'TarXlrOPfaokNOzls2U8' }
  end
end
```

Which worked great until I added the association validation

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies, :through => :positions
  has_many :positions
  validates_presence_of :company
```

How do I add to my factory to achieve this

I tried this

```
 association :company, factory: :company, strategy: :build
```

But all my tests are failing with

```
 undefined method `company=' for #<User:0x007fcd7c13c260>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried simply?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email               { Faker::Internet.email }
    first_name          { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name           { Faker::Name.last_name }
    password            { 'TarXlrOPfaokNOzls2U8' }
    companies           { [Factory(:company, strategy: build)] }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have 1 company per user then you need to use `belongs_to :company` in the User model instead of an has_many. If you really want to have many companies per user, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003871/factory-girl-has-many-associations).

Comment: I know that but I need more then one company....but my validation ensures that I have atleast one

Comment: Actually, your validation should trigger an error unless you have a company_id attribute.

Comment: no actually the 'validates_presence_of :company` is the new way (rails 3.2) of writing validates_existence_of on an association

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a factory for company, user and position, than override the defaults as necessary:

```
  factory :position do
    user
    company
  end
  factory :company do
    #company stuff
  end

  user = create(:user)
  company = create(:company)
  postion = create(:position, user: user, company: company)
  user.company.should eq company
```